# print matrix from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I would like to print adjacency matrix from a dictionary I got from Floyd-Marshall algorithm in network-x. How can I do it? 
I came up with this to see the dictionary as it is:

```
X = nx.floyd_warshall(gra)
Y = {a: dict(b) for a, b in X.items()}
print(Y)
```

and it returns this:

```
{(0, 0): {(0, 0): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (1, 1): 2, (0, 2): 2, (1, 2): 3}, (1, 0): {(1, 0): 0, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 2): 2}, (0, 1): {(0, 1): 0, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 2}, (1, 1): {(1, 1): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (0, 0): 2, (0, 2): 2}, (0, 2): {(0, 2): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (0, 0): 2, (1, 0): 3, (1, 1): 2}, (1, 2): {(1, 2): 0, (1, 1): 1, (0, 2): 1, (0, 0): 3, (1, 0): 2, (0, 1): 2}}
```

Is it possible to memorize in a variable and then print the adjacency matrix?

sample output:

```
       (0,0)  (0,1)   (1,0)  ...
(0,0)    0      1      2      1   ...
(0,1)    1      0      1 
...
(1, 2)   7      6     ...
```

Thanks

Comment: What output are you expecting from this sample matrix dicttionary? Can you also share what `X` is?

Comment: x is the result of the application of floyd-warshall algorithm to my graph

Comment: I added an example of what I would like to get in return (numbers are by chance here)

Comment: Though you will have many repeated edge/length combinations there. Can you share a minimal example? i.e small dictionary and its corresponding adj matrix? Also please clarify a little more your quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty simple idea would be to print the header row which are the keys, then for each pair key/mappings print the values by using the header key to be sure to get the good order

```
keys = vals.keys()
print("       ", *keys)
for k, v in vals.items():
    print(k, ("{:^7}" * len(keys)).format(*(v[k] for k in keys)))

        (0, 0) (1, 0) (0, 1) (1, 1) (0, 2) (1, 2)
(0, 0)    0      1      1      2      2      3   
(1, 0)    1      0      2      1      3      2   
(0, 1)    1      2      0      1      1      2   
(1, 1)    2      1      1      0      2      1   
(0, 2)    2      3      1      2      0      1   
(1, 2)    3      2      2      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just printing it out, you can convert it into a dataframe that you can manipulate.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {(0, 0): {(0, 0): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (1, 1): 2, (0, 2): 2, (1, 2): 3}, (1, 0): {(1, 0): 0, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 2): 2}, (0, 1): {(0, 1): 0, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 2}, (1, 1): {(1, 1): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (0, 0): 2, (0, 2): 2}, (0, 2): {(0, 2): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (0, 0): 2, (1, 0): 3, (1, 1): 2}, (1, 2): {(1, 2): 0, (1, 1): 1, (0, 2): 1, (0, 0): 3, (1, 0): 2, (0, 1): 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      0  1  0  1  0  1
      0  0  1  1  2  2

0 0   0  1  1  2  2  3
1 0   1  0  2  1  3  2
0 1   1  2  0  1  1  2
1 1   2  1  1  0  2  1
0 2   2  3  1  2  0  1
1 2   3  2  2  1  1  0
```

Comment: hi! Is there also a way to set indexes on the first line and in the first column to look like (0,0), (1,0), ... ?

Comment: df.index = [*df.index] and df.columns = [*df.columns]

Comment: Is it possible to do so also with columns name?

Comment: df.columns = [*df.columns]

Comment: You are very welcome. Looks like a fun project. You may find some of these tools helpful: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html

Comment: thanks again!! I've been on nx for a while but I didn't think on using it also for dataframes, thanks for sharing this link!